# Does it make sense to add secure and httpOnly flags to an expired cookie?

Tags: security, cookies, httponly

One of our clients made a penetration test on our application and reported missing flags when working with cookies.

We should always use `httpOnly` and `secure` flags when setting cookies.

After some testing I realized that cookies were actually using this flags when set, but with one exception: Log out.

When logging out some cookies were set with a past expiration date, as to delete that `cookie`, `secure` and `httpOnly` were not used.

Does this represent a security risk? Does it make sense to set these flags when setting an expired cookie?

Answer (score 1):

No, assuming there are no holes in your app, the flag doesn't matter on the log out.

However, you should do what the pen tester says because there may be other security flaws in your app that can be exploited using this cookie if the flags aren't set.  In other words, if your app were otherwise secure then the cookie wouldn't matter, however it probably does matter because there are no guarantees that your app is secure.

One example is an app that doesn't properly terminate or close sessions.  A logout cookie is sent to the client without the flags, and is therefore compromised in some way such as MitM or Wire Sniffing.  The attacker submits the cookie back to the app, along with any other arbitrary data designed to exploit a hole, thus triggering a vulnerability and getting a live session either by resurrecting the previous one or receiving a new one (like the famous NULL session attack).

This is a classic case of one security hole that is useless by itself, but adds a link to a chain that can be used to obtain a compromise.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs are saying two different things?

Comment: For some context, the cookie that's being "insecure" is jsessionidsso (Single sign on valve in Tomcat). And it's set expired when doing a log out and performing a session.invalidate() on server-side.

Comment: @PeeHaa I attempted to clarify.  What I'm trying to say is that if there are no other holes in the app (which is NOT likely), then there is no need for this cookie to be flagged.  However there probably are other holes and therefore it is better to flag the cookie unnecessarily than give the attacker an extra link in the chain.

Comment: @Tinchogob It may be secure now, but in the future somebody may open up a new hole or change something that creates a vulnerability.  This is why pen testers recommend the flag.  They also have to recommend *something* to justify that 5 figures you just paid them for the test :-)

Comment: I don't understand something: expiring the cookie by design does not transmit a value for the cookie. For example `Set-Cookie:mycookie=.; path=/mypath; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;`. There is no value to intercept thus no value that is compromised.